# Why is getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(SOME INTEGER)) NOT working?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a stack of Fragments and trying go back in the stack using getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag() method.

This method does return the object if called this way:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("3")
```

CountingFragment{40d68d00 #2 id=0x7f090000 3}

But it will return NULL if I use the variable as an argument:

```
                int nextLevel = currentPositionInTheStack+1;
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(nextLevel));
```

OR

```
                int nextLevel = currentPositionInTheStack+1;
                String nextLevelTag = "a" + nextLevel;
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(nextLevelTag);
```

Any suggestions why this is happening,

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you sure that nextLevel equals 3?

Comment: In the first code which fails, what happens if you try `String.valueOf(3)`?

Comment: 3 is an example, I tried different integer numbers

Comment: getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(3)) is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have figured out how to navigate forward and back in the stack:

for the forward navigation , if next fragment already exists , used hide() and show() methods:

```
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_fragment);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CountingFragment currentFragment = (CountingFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(currentPositionInTheStack));
                int nextLevel = currentPositionInTheStack+1;
                currentPositionInTheStack++;
                CountingFragment nextFragment = (CountingFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(currentPositionInTheStack));
                if (nextFragment == null) {
                    addFragmentToStack();

                }
                else
                {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.hide(currentFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.show(nextFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                }

            }
        });
```

For the back navigation , had to override onBackPressed method:

```
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();  
            currentPositionInTheStack--;
            Log.d("Current Position In The Stack", String.valueOf(currentPositionInTheStack));
            if (currentPositionInTheStack ==0) {
                //do smth
            } }
```

The  Fragment in the original question was NULL and should be null, though, why it returned the Object , if I did  getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("3"), for example, is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

how do you set your fragmentTag? 
something like this would be necessary:

```
ft.add(fragmentContainerId, mfragment, String.valueOf(++currentPositionInTheStack));
```

Comment: mStackLevel++;

         Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);

         FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_left_enter,
                 R.animator.fragment_slide_left_exit,
                 R.animator.fragment_slide_right_enter,
                 R.animator.fragment_slide_right_exit);
         ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment, String.valueOf(mStackLevel));
         ft.addToBackStack(null);
         ft.commit();

Comment: @katya : Please don't post blocks of code in a comment - it is very difficult to read. Edit your original question and simply leave a comment to tell the person to look at your edited question. In saying that, the second bit of code you posted in the original question will fail because you're pre-pending "a" to the int to make the `nextLevelTag`. In the code you post in the comment above you are setting the tag as the string representation of only the int.

Comment: When adding the  fragment and setting the tag for this fragment, I have tried both String representation and Integer to String Convertion for the tag, but thanks.