# i can't find fragment by tag

Tags: android, android-fragments

i'm trying to find a fragment that i created by tag

```
tachoFrag = (menu1_Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tacho");

overviewFrag= (menu2_Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Overview");

dataLogFrag = (menu3_Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Datalogger");

transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

but when i try to replace the content of the frame i get a null problem because the fragments are not found .... Help?

Comment: You should post more code and your logcat too.

Comment: log cat : 

'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void app.z0nen.slidemenu.menu3_Fragment.setData(double, int, int, double)' on a null object reference at app.z0nen.slidemenu. MyActivity$2.handleMessage (MyActivity.java:270)'

Comment: ' if (tachoFrag != null && tachoFrag.isVisible())
            {
                tachoFrag.setRevs(revs);
                tachoFrag.setSpeed(speed);
                tachoFrag.setFuelGauge(fuel);
                }
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, tachoFrag);
                transaction.commit();
            }
           '

Comment: You should look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825600/findfragmentbytag-returns-null-after-perform-a-fragmenttransaction-using-repla 
and also 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229877/why-is-getfragmentmanager-findfragmentbytagstring-valueofsome-integer-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below codes

```
MyFragment fragment= (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG");
if(null != fragment  && fragment.isVisible()){
    //execute your codes here

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: '          transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           transaction.replace(R.id.container, new     menu1_Fragment(),"Tacho");
            transaction.commit();
           tachoFrag = (menu1_Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tacho");'

 but the logcat keep showing me this error
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void app.z0nen.slidemenu.menu1_Fragment.setRevs(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

In your code `transaction.replace(R.id.container, tachoFrag);` you have not provided the TAG.

it should be `transaction.replace(R.id.container, tachoFrag, "TAG");`

so that you can use `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG")`

Comment: There also seems to be something wrong. You are checking if `tachoFrag.isVisible()` and calling a few methods and then calling replace on the same fragment. Why?